# How to draw a set $\{(x,y): y^2 \leq x^2\}$

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

I want to draw a set $\{(x,y): y^2 \leq x^2\}$. I know what the result should look like (the blue region):

[image]

But I don't really see why is that so. I have

$$ y^2 \leq x^2 $$

I am dividing the domain in two: for $x<0$ and $x \geq 0$ and after square root I get:
$$\pm y \leq \pm x$$
that is:
$$y \leq x$$
$$-y \leq x => y \geq -x$$

and that is fine, but I also get:

$$y \leq -x$$

which is below line for $x$ greater than zero. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\sqrt{}$ is an increasing function,  $y^2 < x^2$ is equivalent to $\sqrt{y^2} < \sqrt{x^2}$, i.e. $|y| < |x|$.  Since $|y| = \max(y, -y)$, that
is equivalent to  ($y < |x|$ and $-y < |x|$).
But $-y < |x|$ is equivalent to $y > -|x|$, so the condition is
$|x| > y > -|x|$.  That is, for $x \ge 0$, $x > y > -x$, and for $x \le 0$, 
$-x > y > x$.

Comment: Thanks now I get it why it is so. But why my thinking is wrong?

Comment: The problem is going from $y^2 < x^2$ to  $\pm y < \pm x$, which is certainly wrong when $x > 0$ and you take the $-x$.

Answer (score 1):

$${\bf x,y\geq0:}\\
x\geq y\\
{\bf x,-y\geq0:}\\
x\geq -y\\
{\bf -x,-y\geq0:}\\
x\leq y\\
{\bf -x,y\geq0:}\\
-x\geq y$$